# Configuring Logstash to not add formatting

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

This simple logstash configuration will move a file from the `input` location to the `output` location:

```
input {
  file { 
    path => "c:/source/*"
    start_position => "beginning"
  } 
}

output {
  file {
    path => "c:/output/myfile.txt"
  }
}
```

However, it will format the ouput in JSON and add other information.

For instance:

```
AAA:111
```

int the input will become

```
{"message":"AAA:111\r","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2015-05-17T10:07:16.470Z","type":"abc","host":"XXXXXX000111","path":"c:/source/test.txt"}
```

in the output.

Is it posible, and if so how, to configure logstash so that the format and contents of the output file matches that of the input file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using [message_format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-file.html#plugins-outputs-file-message_format):

```
output {
    file {
        path => "c:/output/myfile.txt"
        message_format => "%{message}"
    }
}
```